# TypeScript - what do square brackets in property name mean?

Tags: typescript

I saw this TypeScript code somewhere. It compiles without any issues:

```
const eventName = entityName + commandName;
pubsub.publish(triggerName, { [eventName]: response });
```

I assumes it dynamically creates an object literal with property name called eventName. Is this assumption correct? Where in the TypeScript docs is this feature described?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is not a typescript feature but a javascript one. It's called a computed property. [Here are the docs for it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)

Additionally, it does not create a property with the key `eventName`, but instead creates a property with a key that is the value of the variable `eventName`. Eg, if `eventName = "foo"`, then `{[eventName]: "bar"}` is the same as `{foo: "bar"}`.

Comment: Direct link to "Computed property names" section on page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Comment: @MikeHill thanks, I've edited my answer to include your link.